# Slider image issues when Javascript Disabled

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript slider. The slider uses 5-6 images and lines up parallel blocking the text when the javascript is turned off. I just want to display a single image when javascript is turned off. Could you please let me know how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CSS` and put a `class` with `display: none` on the elements you don't want to display. With `JavaScript` you can remove that class then before initializing the slider.